# How to connect to the same document on firestore from different devices?

Tags: javascript, java, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.createCollectionByPlayerID = 
functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
    const citiesRef = db.collection(context.auth.uid);
    let setSf = citiesRef.doc('1SF').set({
        name: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'USA',
        capital: false,
        population: 260
    });
    return "testID"
});
```

I want this function to create separate collections (or document) for every player, named with player's ID. 
When I call this function from one device, the function creates new collection with one name:

[image: pic 1]

When I call the same function from another device, the function creates another collection with another name.

[image: pic 2]

I need to connect to one collection, created by one player, from different devices without creating new collection.

My java code:

```
private void hw_fromFunction() {
    FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mUser.getIdToken(true)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
       String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();

    helloWorldFromFunc(idToken).addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {}
     });
  } else {}
       }
              });
}

private Task<String> helloWorldFromFunc(String idToken) {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("push", true);
    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("createCollectionByPlayerID")
            .call(idToken)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() 
{
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> 
task) throws Exception {
                    return (String) task.getResult().getData();
                }
            });
}
```

How the player can connect to one collection named by his ID from different divices?

===Added some java code:

```
//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*****auth***********
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
         .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
//.requestEmail()
         .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

private void signIn() {Intent signInIntent 
    = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this
            , new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess().addOnCompleteListener(this
            , new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            });
}
```

Rules in Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
```

}

And Log: (sorry for so many text)

```
2019-07-05 10:04:21.134 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2019-07-05 10:04:21.169 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-07-05 10:04:21.281 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
2019-07-05 10:04:21.283 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.signinbutton_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.signinbutton_dynamite:2
2019-07-05 10:04:21.283 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.signinbutton_dynamite, version >= 2
2019-07-05 10:04:21.336 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
2019-07-05 10:04:21.338 8802-8846/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-07-05 10:04:21.343 8802-8846/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
2019-07-05 10:04:21.420 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=28KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.478 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=28KB, data=28KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.478 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.482 8802-8813/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 11835(1178KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1681KB/3MB, paused 781us total 110.398ms
2019-07-05 10:04:21.532 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/AutoManageHelper: starting AutoManage for client 0 false null
2019-07-05 10:04:21.545 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaj$zaa@d0b2a33}
2019-07-05 10:04:21.632 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2019-07-05 10:04:21.643 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-07-05 10:04:21.692 8802-8851/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
2019-07-05 10:04:21.708 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3100986043983932118}]
2019-07-05 10:04:21.716 8802-8851/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
2019-07-05 10:04:21.716 8802-8851/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2019-07-05 10:04:21.755 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-07-05 10:04:21.755 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-07-05 10:04:21.756 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-07-05 10:04:21.756 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-07-05 10:04:21.777 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa0e9a580: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2019-07-05 10:04:21.832 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:21.861 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=33KB, data=53KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.886 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=33KB, data=53KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.886 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2019-07-05 10:04:21.891 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2019-07-05 10:04:21.891 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2019-07-05 10:04:21.915 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-07-05 10:04:21.916 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2019-07-05 10:04:21.928 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 32836187
2019-07-05 10:04:22.022 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:22.052 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=125KB, data=66KB
2019-07-05 10:04:22.052 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=118KB, data=47KB
2019-07-05 10:04:22.061 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=118KB, data=48KB
2019-07-05 10:04:22.061 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=118KB, data=48KB
2019-07-05 10:04:22.061 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2019-07-05 10:04:22.132 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:22.195 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/FA: Connected to remote service
2019-07-05 10:04:22.206 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2019-07-05 10:04:22.208 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:22.259 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2019-07-05 10:04:22.259 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2019-07-05 10:04:22.265 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2019-07-05 10:04:22.276 8802-8802/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 6212 bytes, containing 1 windows, 25 views
2019-07-05 10:04:23.633 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:23.698 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:25.666 8802-8849/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa0e9a580: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaccfb330)
2019-07-05 10:04:27.514 8802-8844/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-07-05 10:05:29.632 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=249KB, data=151KB
2019-07-05 10:05:29.633 8802-8807/com.admiral_odessa.firebaseadmiral1 I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=158KB, data=105KB
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going wrong here. Can you log the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` in the Android code just before invoking the callable?

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, Thank you for reply. I added some java code. May be I do wrong authorization in java?

Comment: I don't see the UID being logged in that output. If you added a statement to print that, are you sure it's being called?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand authorization well. Tell me how to properly log in Firebase.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have registered a user the first thing you should do is save the UID, the collection ID and the document ID. Any subsequent rights or reads should use the collection ID and the document ID as the path, collection\Document ID.

The connection/document ID should be made available to all devices Via User Defaults and/or shared storage. Because User Defaults are Persisted on each device you will need to save the User Defaults on some sort of shared storage.
I used the following key\values - UID\Collection ID and Collection ID/Document ID.

If you allow Firestore to create the document ID it will be unique. So When registering save the above key\values. And then with subsequent logons first check the device’s User Defaults for the connection ID/document ID and use this as your path. If none saved check your shared storage and update the device’s User Defaults.

You can also use Firestore’s command to obtain the collection ID for a user.

Swift/iOS

```
let Database Firestore.firestore()
Database.collection(collection ID).getDocuments{(snapshot, err)}
```

When logging in with an existing account if you don’t find the key\value pairs stored on the User Defaults or the shared storage then you need to take appropriate action according to your application.